# How to use Eigen Jacobi SVD with Eigen Affine Matrix

Tags: c++, computer-vision, eigen, svd

**Problem** :I am trying to calculate the SVD of a rotation matrix using the Eigen JacobiSVD module to calculate the single value decomposition of a rotation matrix.

**Expected** : I should be able to pass my rotation matrix of type Eigen::Affine3d to the svd method and then use the U and V from the SVD to produce a new rotation matrix of type Eigen::Affine3d.

**Observed** The svd method does not accpet my tSixDof matrix as an acceptable parameter.

**Question** Why can't I use an affine matrix as the input? Is there a better way to perform this operation?

```
// Resolve numerical errors in the rotation matrix by implementing the 
// orthogonal procrustes problem algorithm.

void SixDof::resolveRotation()
{
   //initial SixDof
   SixDof tSixDof;

   Eigen::Index n = tSixDof.rows();
   Eigen::Index m = tSixDof.rows();

   Eigen::Matrix3d U;
   Eigen::Matrix3d V;
   Eigen::Matrix3d R;

   Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::Matrix3d> svd(tSixDof.rotation() 
   Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);
   U = svd.matrixU();
   V = svd.matrixV();

   R = U*V.transpose();
   //Resolved SixDof
   tSixDof.rotation() = R;

 }
```

The SixDof class

```
class SixDof : public Eigen::Affine3d 
{
public:
SixDof();
SixDof(const Eigen::Affine3d& aOther);
void resolveRotation();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 3x3 rotation matrix is not an Affine3D transform. From the documentation: "Generic affine transformations are represented by the Transform class which internally is a (Dim+1)^2 matrix.". To perform Procrustes for adjusting your noisy rotation matrix M you need to be calling svd with a 3x3 Eigen matrix (storing M).

Comment: Thank you, yes I realize that now and I am using the method tSixDof.rotation() now instead of tSixDof. However, I don't know how to set the elements of my roation matrix that is used by SixDof. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your question isn't clear as you didn't give the class definition of SixDoF.

Comment: I just added the definition. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I really wouldn't extend the Affine class. Your signature shows you're not adding any extra useful functionality to it and it's best avoid subclassing Eigen types. If your affine transform matrix is A you get the noisy rotation component by A.matrix().block(0,0,3,3)

Comment: Thank you A.matrix().block(0,0,3,3) was what I needed!